# Creating a copy of worksheet in a loop

Tags: vba, excel, copy, excel-2007

I am trying to copy a selection of sheets, saving each one as a different file. It keeps giving me an `error 1004` saying that `Copy method of Worksheet class failed`. Selecting the `Sheets(i).Copy` line. I need it to do the sheet copy rather than copy and paste the value elsewhere as I need the formatting to be carried over.

Can anyone help fix the error as I can't locate what I've done wrong?

```
Sub CSR()

Dim wb As Workbook, First As Integer, Last As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

filepath = "H:\Finance\Danny Bland\"
wb.Activate
First = Sheets("LIVE FLEET").Index
Last = Sheets("Email Attachment").Index

For i = First + 1 To Last - 1


wb.Activate
Set wk = wb.Sheets(i)
wk.Activate
filename = Sheets(i).Name
Sheets(i).Activate
Sheets(i).Copy

Cells.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filepath & filename & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of `i` when the code breaks?

Comment: It doesn't actually do anything so I assume it is `2` as this is the first value used

Comment: Ok here's the deal: when you try to reference a `Sheet` with an index `i` you need to make sure that Sheet with such index actually exists. There are multiple ways to handle this but if you could give us a screenshot of you sheets collections structure that would help us come up with a solution.

Comment: do you want to export all sheets or just certain ones?

Comment: I want to export all sheets that aren't the first sheet, or last sheet, which is what the counter does, I have used the same counter elsewhere and that has worked. Due to the way its worked out, it will never be taking an index that isn't used?

Comment: It appears to have just been a strange issue. I got fed up, closed my excel, reopened and pasted in the code above and it worked. Frustrating that it wouldn't work earlier but glad it does now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Const filepath As String = "H:\Finance\Danny Bland\"

Sub CSR()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wk As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Activate

    For Each wk In Sheets ' for all sheets in the workbook
        ' if sheet name isn't live fleet or email attachment
        If wk.Name <> "LIVE FLEET" Or wk.Name <> "Email Attachment" Then
            ExportSheet wk ' you want to export it
        End If
    Next

End Sub

' you may need to modify this so exactly suit your needs
Private Sub ExportSheet(sh As Worksheet)

    sh.Copy
    sh.Cells.Copy
    sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    sh.SaveAs filename:=filepath & sh.Name & ".xlsx"
    sh.Parent.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Not really sure what I need to edit to make this work. Any reason it can't be done with an `i` loop?

Comment: @DannyBland I can but if you sheet indexes shift for any reason the code will probably break everytime. Iterating the sheets collection and excluding the 2 sheets seems more reasonable in this case -> you get reference to each sheet that is not "Live fleet" or "Email attachment" disregard of their indexes.

Comment: The first sheet will always be the first sheet, and last will always be last. There may be sheets placed in the middle but that shouldn't cause any additional problems?

Comment: @DannyBland currently your last sheet's index may be 3 (if you got 3 sheets) but adding more sheets and using your method will only and always work for the no. 2 sheet and not take newly added sheets in to consideration because their .index property will be higher than your "last sheet".

Comment: If you do however want to stick to using the index add some checks like if `last -1 >= first + 1` etc

Comment: Ah so index isn't about where they're placed it's about when they were created?

Comment: There were a few hidden worksheets that I wasn't made aware of, so I found the easiest way was to make a list of the pages I needed, do a count for all non empty cells in the range and do a loop for those values.